# Is possible to know where my UserControl is

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Suppose that I have a UserControl, and I use it in different pages.

From the codebehind my userControl, is it possible to know dynamically which pages it is in?

MyUserControl.xaml

```
    <UserContol bla bla bla
            bla bla bla
            x:Name=ucbox>
        other xml stuffs
    </UserContol>
```

Page1

```
        <Page x:Class="Page1"
             xmlns:local=using:"path of userContol">

             <local:myuserControl     />
        </Page>
```

Page2

```
    <Page x:Class="Page2"
         xmlns:local=using:"path of userContol">

           <local:myuserControl     />
    </Page>
```

MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
//how can i do that?
var p = get the root of the Page1 or 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the actual control object, you can vertically traverse the visual tree. Or, you can use the extensions included in the [`WinRTXamlToolkit`](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com) to do something like `mycontrol.GetAncestors<Page>()`.

EDIT* (Filip Skakun)

If you don't want/need the full toolkit - you can just use this bit of the `VisualTreeHelperExtensions`:

```
public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAncestorsOfType<T>(this DependencyObject start) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        return start.GetAncestors().OfType<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetAncestors(this DependencyObject start)
    {
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(start);

        while (parent != null)
        {
            yield return parent;
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how i can vertically traverse the visual tree? using `VisualTreeHelper` i cannot see any method that can help me.

Comment: `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` is how you traverse *up* the tree, `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` is how you traverse *down* the tree.

Comment: using  `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(ucbox)` i get the root of the userController xaml, how can I get the root of the page1 (or page2) using the VisualTreeHelper?

Comment: The `VisualTree` is a [Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) structure. What you have just done is gone up one level. Now what you need to do is keep going up levels until you get to control you are looking for (the Page). The easiest way to do this is with a recursive function (`FindAncestorOfType`, for instance). Use `GetParent` and store it in a variable (`parent`). If it's the object you are looking for, you are done and can `return parent`, otherwise `return FindAncestorOfType(parent);` (or `parent.FindAncestorOfType(type)` if you make it an extension method).

Comment: To repeat the note in my answer, the [`WinRTXamlToolkit`](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com) has this method already added. All you have to do is install it form nuget, add the `using` statement, then call `ucbox.GetFirstAncestorOfType<Page>();`.

Answer (score 0):

In typical situations your `Page` is in a `Frame` that is at the root of the visual tree, so you can also grab it starting at the root this way:

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

if (frame != null)
{
    var page = frame.Content as Page;

    if (page != null)
    {
        // you have found you page!
    }
    else
    {
        // the frame has not loaded a page yet - this isn't very likely to happen
    }
}
else
{
    // the app is either not initialized yet
    // or you have modified the default template and Frame is not at the root.
}
```

Comment: in this way you get the root of the app at first, to descent the tree. is it right? What i want is not that, i want to ascend the tree from the UC to the page that use it.

Comment: What's the difference? I simply show it as the alternative option that doesn't involve walking the (potentially tall) visual tree and so might perform better.